# InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() on Mac Os

Tags: java, macos

On Mac Os 10.9 and Java 1.7.0_40 returns

```
InetAddress in = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.108");
System.out.println("Hostname: " + in.getCanonicalHostName());
```

`192.168.0.108` instead of `red.local`. `192.168.0.108` is a hosts IP in local network. On Linux and on Windows works this just like expected. It looks like a Java.

Comment: That's interesting, what is your question?

Comment: Thу question is: Should I report this issue to oracle?